# openstack dashboard gives internal server error

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

when i try to open dashboard it gives internal server error. It was running fine earlier but suddenly this error occurred.

Here is my apache log :

```
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321423 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599] mod_wsgi (pid=31878): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi'.
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321468 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321485 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321506 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     self.load_middleware()
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321607 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321620 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     mw_instance = mw_class()
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321625 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 23, in __init__
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321633 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321637 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 372, in url_patterns
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321644 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321648 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in urlconf_module
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321654 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321658 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321665 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     __import__(name)
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321669 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/urls.py", line 35, in <module>
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321676 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     url(r'^api/', include('openstack_dashboard.api.rest.urls')),
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321680 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 28, in include
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321687 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321691 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321697 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     __import__(name)
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321701 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321708 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599]     from openstack_dashboard.api import base
[Fri Jun 23 16:43:50.321726 2017] [:error] [pid 31878:tid 140589128623872] [remote 10.0.30.11:41599] ImportError: cannot import name base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google for this error, you will find a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1125622) on Launchpad, with a long rambling set of comments.  The last one says:

> From the responses here it seems that the root issue with those encountering this "bug" is that their Horizon installation is missing some dependency, and installing that dependency fixes the issue.
>
> The error reported "ImportError: cannot import name base" is a symptom of the failure to load all dependent modules.
>
> The cause therefore would appear to be incomplete or erroneous installation documentation.

(Or possibly ... failure to follow the installation instructions.)

In short, check that you have installed the correct versions of all of the dependencies for Horizon.

A second [bug report](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2014-March/107594.html) may offer more clues.

---

You say:

> It was running fine earlier but suddenly this error occurred.

That might be due to update / patch being applied.